# Halcon: numLevels parameter of FindNccModel has problem

Tags: halcon

If set numLevels to 'auto' and minScore = 0.99, it cannot find the model created on the same image.

Change the minScore to 0.8, get a result with score 1

It seems the minScore didn't work good on mulitple levels, but set numLevels to 1 will increase processing time from 2ms to 40ms.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
create_ncc_model (Image, 'auto', 0, 0, 'auto', 'use_polarity', ModelID)
find_ncc_model (Image1, ModelID, 0, 0, 0.99, 1, 0.5, 'false', 0, Row, Column, Angle, Score)
```